# How could I automate the installation of this "qemu-kvm " if I have to enter several inputs?

Tags: bash, automation, dockerfile, prompt, kvm

I would like to install the following:

```
apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils cpu-checker
```

but during the process I have to enter yes, 77 , 1 , 1, 1 as a inputs to finish the installation. How could I automate this process using prompt, the idea it's do it in Dockerfile.
Thanks in adavance

Comment: Have you tried [tag:expect]?

Comment: @MiguelAguilera : Does the installer read from stdin? In this case you could prepare an answer file and use input redirection.

Comment: Finally I used DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt-get install -y qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils cpu-checker and it worked fine.